# R - transform columns containing key values into multiple columns, in a data.frame object

Tags: r

Considering the following `data.frame` object `df`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  month = c(   1,    1,    1,    2,    2,    3,    3),
  type  = c("T1", "T1", "T4", "T2", "T3", "T1", "T3"),
  value = c(  10,   40,   20,   30,   10,   40,   50)
)

#   month type value
# 1     1   T1    10
# 2     1   T1    40
# 3     1   T4    20
# 4     2   T2    30
# 5     2   T3    10
# 6     3   T1    40
# 7     3   T3    50
```

How can `df` be processed to produce the result below?

```
#   month T1 T2 T3 T4
# 1     1 10  0  0  0
# 2     1 40  0  0  0
# 3     1  0  0  0 20
# 4     2  0 30  0  0
# 5     2  0  0 10  0
# 6     3 40  0  0  0
# 7     3  0  0 50  0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df2 <- df %>%
  mutate(ID = 1:n()) %>%
  spread(type, value, fill = 0) %>%
  select(-ID)
```

Comment: What's the motivation to create the ID variable? I see that an error is thrown if ID is not created, but why this happens? It seems unintuitive for me.

Comment: Before using the `spread` function, each row needs a unique ID. If you remove the `mutate` line, R will through an error.